# ¿Cómo abrir la cámara de un teléfono desde Android?

Tags: android

Hola chicos estoy tratando de que al abrir mi app , lo primero que se haga se abra la cámara y me salen varios errores , estoy intentando implementarlo de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no he podido lograrlo.

Comment: Buenos días, para mejor legibilidad si pones el código en formato texto/código antes de una imagen y el log resultante para ver donde puede estar el error.

Comment: Si eres desarrollador y deseas preguntar en StackOverflow teniendo un problema, es demasiado importante agregar los mensajes de error que sean desplegados en la consola. En el caso de Android siempre trata de agregar los mensajes del StackTrace desplegados en el LogCat. A simple vista me parece que necesitas agregar los import adecuados y de hecho la clase "sulfaceHolder" no es parte del SDK Android =(

Answer (score 6):

Agrego un la forma de realizarlo, primeramente agrega los permisos dentro de AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Creamos la clase `CameraView` que es basada en tu código original:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
        super(context);

        mCamera = camera;
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreater" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)
            return;

        try{
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR",  e.getMessage());
        }

        try{
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
}
```

Para cargar la vista creamos una actividad, en la cual primeramente definimos el layout, `activity_camera.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgClose"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Definimos nuestra actividad, la cual debe estar registrada dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";


    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//agrega la vista CameraView()
        }

        //boton para cerrar la aplicación.
        ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
        imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Cierra la actividad.
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Al ejecutar nuestra aplicación, se abrirá la camara :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente te comento que este ejemplo usa la clase [Camera](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) la cual es obsoleta desde la API 21, aún la puedes usar, pero se recomienda el uso de la clase **[Camera2](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)**

#### Para Android 6.0 agrego método para solicitar permisos.

```
private void checkCameraPermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para la camara!.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Tienes permiso para usar la camara.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que para Android 6 ha cambiado la manera de solicitar permisos.

Comment: Gracias Hector, cuando usamos un target sdk con la última versión debemos de  implementar una petición de permisos, pero para este ejemplo considero suficiente. El tema de permisos para Android 6 es otro tema que seguramente alguien preguntara en un futuro, saludos!

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, agregando método para solicitar permisos en Android 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Da estos permisos en el AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Y luego esta Constante

```
public final static int RESP_TOMAR_FOTO = 1000;
```

luego en el metodo que quieras:

```
public void onClickTomarFoto(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String filePath = Util.DirApp().getPath() + "/foto.jpg";

    Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESP_TOMAR_FOTO);
}
```

Por ultimo para obtener la respuesta de la camara :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RESP_TOMAR_FOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    }
}
```