# Uso de la camara desde android

Tags: android

Desarrollando una app, me he topado con una duda.

Mi intencion es que al pulsar un boton, se active la camara, y la foto, o las fotos que se hagan, se redirijan a una carpeta previamente establecida.

Estoy testando en Android 6, por lo que imagino que habra que solicitar permisos y tal...

alguien podria mostrar algun ejemplo sobre el tema?

Comment: Sergio, Un ejemplo esta ya comentado en esta pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8418/95

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes al [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) con mas ejemplos. Básicamente para usar la aplicación de la cámara que viene en el teléfono debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// esto va en la declaracion de la clase, se usa en onActivityResult
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1234;

... // luego en algún botón pones esto

Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

La activity que invoca esto tiene que sobrecarger el metodo `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // verificar que vuelva de la camara
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE ) {
        // asegurarse que tomo la fotografia (pudo cancelar)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            // este image view muestra la fotografia.
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Ademas necesitas autorizar a la APP a usar la cámara, agrega esto al manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo importante en Android 6.0 es solicitar los permisos para la cámara, para esto puedes usar este método:

```
private void checkCameraPermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para la Camara.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para usar la camara!");
    }
}
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como abrir la camara :
[¿Cómo abrir la cámara de un teléfono desde Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8399/c%C3%B3mo-abrir-la-c%C3%A1mara-de-un-tel%C3%A9fono-desde-android/8418#8418) y puedes revisar detalles en la [documentación.](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView)

Lo que realizarías es, desde un boton agregar un listener el cual active la camara:

```
   Button botonCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
   botonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//agrega la vista CameraView()
         }
        }
    });
```

Pero si deseas que se guarden las fotos en un path especifico puedes realizarlo mediante el intent:

```
   Button botonCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
   botonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
       Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/mi_folder/mi_foto.png"));
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(camera, 1); 
       }
    });
```