# Abrir cámara con aplicación de android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

Estoy tratando de abrir la cámara desde mi aplicativo, pero al momento de que la quiero abrir me sale un error, estoy aprendiendo apenas la creación de estas aplicaciones y aun no se leer bien los errores

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { 
act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE 
cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } from 
ProcessRecord{bd3e6b7 4753:com.demonsystem.trackingticket/u0a94} (pid=4753, 
uid=10094) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

y me marca la linea de mi codigo

```
 btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i,0);
                ocultar();
            }
        });
```

> Petición de permisos

```
private void checkCameraPermission() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para la camara!.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 225);
        } else {
            Log.i("Mensaje", "Tienes permiso para usar la camara.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: en android 6.0 o superior, debes implementar permisos en tiempo de ejecucion, por eso creo que es el error

Comment: @zhet he actualizado mi pregunta ya que le agregue lo de los permisos pero aun asi me sigue dando error

Comment: ¿Rechazaste el acceso a la cámara? Tiene pinta de que revocaste los permisos o no los gestionaste bien. A partir de Android M si tienes los permisos de cámara en la aplicación no puedes lanzar la aplicación de cámara mediante Intent. ¿Podrías compartir el código completo o un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para reproducir tu error? Échale un vistazo entre tanto a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos además de la excelente respuesta de Joacer, puedes revisar en el sitio, puedes encontrar más información acerca de esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=abrir+camara  por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8399/c%C3%B3mo-abrir-la-c%C3%A1mara-de-un-tel%C3%A9fono-desde-android/8418#8418

Answer (score 3):

Deberías echarle un vistazo a la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es-419) de Android sobre permisos, en ella te explica los pasos a seguir para hacer una buena gestión de los permisos:

> No obstante, el efecto de esa declaración es diferente según la
>   versión del sistema y el nivel de SDK de destino de tu app:
>
> - Si el dispositivo tiene Android 5.1 o una versión anterior, o el nivel
>     de SDK de destino de tu app es el 22 o uno inferior: Si tienes un
>     [**permiso peligroso**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) en tu manifiesto, el usuario debe conceder el
>     permiso cuando instale la app; si no otorga el permiso, el sistema no
>     instalará la app.
> - Si el dispositivo tiene Android 6.0 o una versión
>     posterior, y el nivel de SDK de destino de tu app es el 23 o uno
>     posterior: Los permisos deben estar indicados en el manifiesto de la
>     app, y esta debe solicitar cada [**permiso peligroso**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) que necesite mientras
>     la app esté en ejecución. El usuario puede conceder o negar cada
>     permiso y la app puede continuar ejecutándose con capacidades
>     limitadas aun cuando el usuario rechace una solicitud de permiso.
>
> **Nota:** A partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios pueden
>   revocar permisos desde cualquier app en cualquier momento, aunque la
>   app esté orientada a un nivel de API inferior. Debes probar tu app
>   para verificar que se comporte correctamente cuando no cuente con un
>   permiso necesario, independientemente del nivel de API al que esté
>   orientada tu app.

Además, [antes de Android M](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) la aplicación podía lanzar la aplicación de cámara incluso sin tener permisos de cámara en su manifiesto, a partir de Android M si está declarad el permiso éste debe concederse:

> **Note:** if you app targets M and above and declares as using the CAMERA
>   permission which is not granted, then attempting to use this action
>   will result in a `SecurityException`.

Por lo que he podido ver en tu código haces una petición de los permisos, pero no puedo ver si la haces al pulsar el botón de la cámara o al entrar a la actividad, independientemente de eso veo que te falta controlar la respuesta de la solicitud  de permisos.

A continuación te dejaré un ejemplo de cómo pedir permiso al pulsar el botón de la cámara, y cómo controlar el resultado.

**Solicitar los permisos que se necesitan**

```
btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {// Marshmallow+
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                } else {
                    // No se necesita dar una explicación al usuario, sólo pedimos el permiso.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMARA );
                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMARA es una constante definida en la app. El método callback obtiene el resultado de la petición.
                 }
            }else{ //have permissions
                 abrirCamara ();
            }
        }else{ // Pre-Marshmallow
            abrirCamara ();
        }
    }
});
```

**Controla la respuesta a la solicitud de permisos**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMARA : {
            // Si la petición es cancelada, el array resultante estará vacío.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {    
                // El permiso ha sido concedido.
                abrirCamara ();
            } else {    
                // Permiso denegado, deshabilita la funcionalidad que depende de este permiso.
            }
            return;
        }    
        // otros bloques de 'case' para controlar otros permisos de la aplicación
    }
}
```

**Abrir la cámara**

```
public void abrirCamara (){
     Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     startActivityForResult(i,0);
     ocultar();
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Justo lo que le estaba contando en los comentarios :) Si no te importa te pido permiso para editar tu respuesta y agregar enlaces y referencias a la documentación de Android.

Comment: @OscarGarcia perfecto! así le resultará más útil a más personas

Comment: Hecho, puedes revisar mi edición, completarla o aclararla. Te recomendaría usar el [estilo de programación recomendado para desarrolladores AOSP Android](https://source.android.com/source/code-style). Si quieres puedo editarte el código para que se ajuste a las recomendaciones.

Comment: Sin problema @OscarGarcia

Comment: Es que es un tema muy controvertido a partir de Android M.. Puedes verlo en este hilo: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37063818](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37063818) mis aplicaciones las tengo contra API 19 (Android 4.4), por lo que no suelo sufrir este problema.. pero alguna que otra vez que he tratado de hacer una de cero para APIs superiores me han dado quebraderos de cabeza por lo que siempre termino cambiando el `target` x( Por cierto, gracias. Este hilo y tu respuesta me ha animado a retomar el tema y tratar de migrar algunas al 23 (M).

Comment: si, yo con el permiso de la cámara no había tenido que lidiar anteriormente, en las apps que he hecho he tenido que usar otros permisos como el de accounts o los de storage, y con el tema de permisos siempre acabas liándote. Gracias a ti @OscarGarcia por ampliar la respuesta!!

Answer (score 1):

bueno además de la solicitud de permisos en tiempo de ejecucción yo también los pongo en el manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

En el intent de la imagen lo uso así

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

También si hay un error al preguntar por los permisos, yo le agrego android antes de manifest `"android.manifest.permission.CAMERA"`