# Abrir camara frontal android studio 5.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas quisiera saber si me pueden guiar en el problema que poseo, tengo dispositivo android 5.1 API level 22 y estoy intentando abrir la cámara frontal desde el accionar de un botón, sin embargo a pesar de todos los intentos que he realizado solo he conseguido abrir la cámara posterior y luego pasar a la cámara frontal, pero yo quiero partir directamente en la cámara frontal.

Para abrir la cámara posterior he realizado varios tipos de intents y estos funcionan sin problemas pero la camara frontal no consigo abrirla.

Saludos

Comment: Eloy recuerda que cuando preguntes agregues lo que hayas realizado o investigado, en este caso agrega que problema tienes o que mensaje de error se despliega en el LogCat, revisa [ask]. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio

Answer (score -2):

REVISA ESTE POST MUY COMPLETO DE UNO DE NUESTROS COMPAÑEROS.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8418/105569

De igual forma adjunto el texto de dicho post para que visualices, por favor visita dicho post y dale los créditos de respuesta a nuestro compañero.

---

Agrego un la forma de realizarlo, primeramente agrega los permisos dentro de AndroidManifest.xml :

Creamos la clase CameraView que es basada en tu código original:

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);

    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreater" + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        return;

    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR",  e.getMessage());
    }

    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

}

Para cargar la vista creamos una actividad, en la cual primeramente definimos el layout, activity_camera.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
```

Definimos nuestra actividad, la cual debe estar registrada dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml :

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";


private Camera mCamera = null;
private CameraView mCameraView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(mCamera != null) {
        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//agrega la vista CameraView()
    }

    //boton para cerrar la aplicación.
    ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Cierra la actividad.
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Al ejecutar nuestra aplicación, se abrirá la camara :

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

Finalmente te comento que este ejemplo usa la clase Camera la cual es obsoleta desde la API 21, aún la puedes usar, pero se recomienda el uso de la clase Camera2

Para Android 6.0 agrego método para solicitar permisos.

private void checkCameraPermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para la camara!.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Tienes permiso para usar la camara.");
    }
}

Comment: respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad, lee [answer] añade lo relevante del link aqui y mejora aún mas el contenido, pues si la página deja de estar funcional el contendo se pierde

Comment: y dale los créditos al autor original

Comment: muchas gracias @shadow por siempre estar al tanto de las respuestas te agradezco.

Comment: no me funciona esa respuesta